# Borland StarTeam 2008 - How to Recover file + file History

Tags: file, recovery, starteam

I accidently delete a file from the Starteam repository,
I am able to view the file content on different view/configuration, and I am able to copy it and recheck-in the file but its history is important.
Is it possible to restore the file along with its history?

Thank you
Sharon whipple

Answer (score 4):

Create a new view (**View > New...**) based on a label attached to the file you want to restore, or based on a time before the file was deleted.  Switch to this view (**View > Select View...**).  Use VCM to promote (Under "Select the type of compare or merge:, choose **Promote**) to the tip view (**View > Compare/Merge...**).  Before committing, check that the file to be restored has action *Reverse share* associated with it.  Commit (**VCM Session > Commit Changes...**).  The file should now be restored to the tip view.

Answer (score 0):

On page 37, this document ( http://www.nohau.se/products/starteam/StarTeam-2008-Best-Practices.pdf ) recommends going to a previous view/configuration and then sharing the file with your tip view.  You can share a file by having both views open in your graphical client, and Ctrl-Clicking the deleted file from your old view and dragging it to your tip view (it will prompt you about sharing the file).

Comment: Thank you
The peroblem with this concept is that if other view/configuration is frozen, Users will not be able to change the file...